# Shrink container to smaller child rather than expanding to fill parent

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm creating a custom widget for a segment control.

```
return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
  child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue)),
    child: Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: buttons,
    ),
  ),
);
```

I want the container to shrink to the minimum size to contain its children.  However when I include the widget in a parent, it expands to fill the parent.  This is visible because the border from the decoration is larger than the buttons.

How do I force the container to shrink?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To get the container not to take up the entire parent, you need to tell it where it should be placed within the parent - by default, it doesn't know where to go so it fills the parent =D.

The simplest ways of doing this are to use an [`Align`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html) or a [`Center`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Center-class.html) widget. I believe you want to put it around your `Container` in this case, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Wrapping it in a Center did what I wanted.  Thanks.

Comment: Tried wrapping a container with Center. It doesn't work.. it still wrap the whole screen..

Comment: As @bashan pointed out, this is not the full solution, only a "this might work sometimes for some reason".

Comment: @fgblomqvist There's a multitude of reasons why it wouldn't work, but they are completely dependent on what the content you are wrapping with a center is. In the OPs case, _which is what this answer is about_, it does work. If you have a situation in which this doesn't help feel free to ask a question. The question's title is rather generic though.

Comment: @rmtmckenzie fair enough, although not completely true. They are also dependent on what you have that will wrap the Align or Center. Therefore, I think you could do a better job explaining why this works and why it might not work. E.g. talking about the constraints and how they're communicated to the children/parents.

Answer (score 12):

wrapping a Container in a Row() widget makes the container shrinks to the Container's child size as mentioned here,,
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/4949

```
Row(
 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
 crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
   children: [
     Container(
       child:button()   
     ),
   ]
),
```

Answer (score 1):

bit late to the party... I'm still new to flutter so go easy on me, but I think using `Align` or `Center` as the `Parent` and then set the `Width` and `Height` values for the `Child` then the parent should shrink to the child. =D

Answer (score 1):

As your component will grow to fill the parent, you can wrap your component inside a Row and give it minimum axis size. If you want to center it, you will need to wrap the Row inside a Center widget too:

```dart
Center(
  child: Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: [YourComponent]
  )
);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Container(
    height: 16,
    // width: 50,
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0xffeeeeee),
        child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: []
        ),
    )
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add `Align` widget to the container and it will make it fix the child widget

Comment: The child size is not the problem. It's that the container expands to its parent instead of shrinking to its children.